# Can I overwrite BitBucket environment variables on specific conditions?

Tags: bash, shell, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to overwrite my repository secrets for Prod with Test credentials based on specific attributes provided as input to BitBucket Pipeline, however running into an issue.

```
if [[  “$parent_ou_id " == “xyz” ]]; then AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=“$TEST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID” ; AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=“$TEST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY” ; fi
```

**Error**

```
conditional binary operator expected
```

Comment: Can you try this ?
`if [[  “$parent_ou_id " == “xyz” ]]; then export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=“$TEST_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID”  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=“$TEST_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY” ; fi
`

Comment: I tried it , although the query executed successfully, the pipeline is still pointing to PROD instead of test. Guess the Repository secrets were not overwritten.

Comment: Can you try to apply the one on the answer maybe it can help.

Comment: Your script is full of smart quotes. Change each `“` to `"`, and from now on avoid editing code in a word processor like MS Word or Google Docs. Always use a text editor or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I assume your structure is something like;

```
pipelines:
    tags:
    '*-test*':
      - step:
          name: "beta step name"
          deployment: beta
          script:
            - <script>
    '*-prod':
      - step:
          name: "prod step name"
          deployment: prod
          script:
            - <script>
```

The important field here is **deployment** argument. You can define different deployment names for your environments and different variables with the same names.

As document points ;

`You can add, edit, or remove variables at the account, repository, and deployment environment levels. If you use the same name as an existing variable, you can override it. The order of overrides is Deployment > Repository > Account > Default variables. Each deployment environment is independent so you can use the same variable name with different values for each environment.`

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/